# Reorder XML Elements in Extendscript Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I want to reorder the following list of movies in such a way that movies of the `version==3D` should be placed before the ones in `version==2D`.

**Input**

```xml
<films>
  <film name="Foobar" version="2D"></film>
  <film name="Foobar" version="3D"></film>
  <film name="Foobaz" version="2D"></film>
  <film name="Foobaz" version="3D"></film>
</films>
```

**Desired Output**

```xml
<films>
  <film name="Foobar" version="3D"></film>
  <film name="Foobar" version="2D"></film>
  <film name="Foobaz" version="3D"></film>
  <film name="Foobaz" version="2D"></film>
</films>
```

I've fiddled around and ended up with the following code. Hopefully it understandable.

```js
/***
 Extend Array prototype to have a indeOf function
 ***/
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(item) { 
    var index = 0, length = this.length;  
    for ( ; index < length; index++ ) {
        if ( this[index] == item )  
            return index;  
        }  
    return -1;  
};  


var xmlString = '\
<films>\
    <film name="Foobar" version="2D"></film>\
    <film name="Foobar" version="3D"></film>\
    <film name="Foobaz" version="2D"></film>\
    <film name="Foobaz" version="3D"></film>\
</films>';

var xml = new XML(xmlString);
var sortVersion = ['2D', '3D'];
var uniqueMovies = new Array();


for (var index = 0; index < xml.elements().length(); index++) {
    if (index == 0) continue;

    // Fetch meta data of previous movie
    var prevTitle = xml.elements()[index - 1].@name;
    var prevVersion = xml.elements()[index - 1].@version;
    var prevVersionIdx = sortVersion.indexOf(prevVersion);

    // Fetch meta data of current movie
    var curTitle = xml.elements()[index].@name;
    var curVersion = xml.elements()[index].@version;
    var curVersionIdx = sortVersion.indexOf(curVersion);

    // If both movie title matches verify which movie should be prioritized
    if (prevTitle == curTitle) {
      if (prevVersionIdx < curVersionIdx) { 
          // Movie prio movie before less prio movie
          xml.insertChildBefore(xml.elements()[index - 1], xml.elements()[index]);
          // And delete the next in index
          delete xml.elements()[index + 1];
      }
    }   
}

$.writeln("-----");
$.writeln("");
$.writeln(xml.elements().toString());
return xml
```

However when I run this script I end with the following result where nothing is changed at all although the both if condition are hit and the element on `index[1]` is added before `index[0]`.

```xml
<films>
  <film name="Foobar" version="2D"/>
  <film name="Foobar" version="3D"/>
  <film name="Foobaz" version="2D"/>
  <film name="Foobaz" version="3D"/>
</films>
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: are you sure that the script finds a scenario where both of the if tests pass?

Comment: Hi there, yes I am pretty sure that the condition triggers.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `if (prevTitle == curTitle)` condition ? I also recommend that you edit your question to show your desired xml output.

Comment: This condition is to verify if I am in a sitatuion where I would need to analyse the sorting 3D before 2D. The input XML is already sorted by Titles, but no by version.

Comment: I think moving would be better than creating/inserting and deleting. See an example of moving in the accepted answer here:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/879586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following approach instead:

**script.jsx**

```js
/**
 * Extend Array prototype to have a indexOf function
 */
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(item) {
    var index = 0, length = this.length;
    for ( ; index < length; index++ ) {
        if ( this[index] == item )
            return index;
        }
    return -1;
};

var xmlString = '\
<films>\
  <film name="Foobar" version="2D"></film>\
  <film name="Foobar" version="3D"></film>\
  <film name="Foobaz" version="2D"></film>\
  <film name="Foobaz" version="3D"></film>\
  <film name="Foo" version="3D"></film>\
  <film name="Quux" version="2D"></film>\
  <film name="Quux" version="3D"></film>\
</films>';

var xml = new XML(xmlString);
var sortVersion = ['2D', '3D'];

// 1. Create a temporary XML object with a  matching `films` root element.
var tempXml = new XML('<' + xml.name() + '></' + xml.name() + '>');

for (var index = 0, max = xml.elements().length(); index < max; index++) {

  // Fetch meta data of previous movie
  var prevTitle = String(xml.elements()[index - 1].@name);
  var prevVersion = xml.elements()[index - 1].@version;
  var prevVersionIdx = sortVersion.indexOf(prevVersion);

  // Fetch meta data of current movie
  var curTitle = String(xml.elements()[index].@name);
  var curVersion = xml.elements()[index].@version;
  var curVersionIdx = sortVersion.indexOf(curVersion);

  // 2. Insert each XML element node from the original XML Object into
  // the temporary XML Object and position (i.e. sort) as neccessary.
  if (prevTitle === curTitle && prevVersion < curVersion) {
    tempXml.insertChildBefore(tempXml.elements()[index -1], xml.elements()[index])
  } else {
    // There's nothing to change (i.e. sort) so insert it as-is .
    tempXml.insertChildBefore(tempXml.elements()[index], xml.elements()[index])
  }
}

// 3. Overwrite original XML object's children with temporary (sorted) XML objects children.
xml.setChildren(tempXml.children());

// 4. Delete temporary XML object.
tempXml = undefined;


// Testing...
$.writeln(xml)
$.writeln('-----------------')
$.writeln(xml.elements().length())
$.writeln('-----------------')
```

---

**Explanation:**

Instead of attempting to manipulate (i.e. sort) the original XML Object the gist above does the following instead:

1. Creates another XML Object that contains a `<films>` root element only. This XML Object will be temporary.
2. During each turn of the `for` loop we;

   - Insert a clone of each XML element node from the original XML Object into the temporary XML Object.
   - Position (i.e. sort) each XML element node as necessary.
3. Overwrite the original XML objects child element nodes with child element nodes from the temporary/sorted XML Object.
4. Finally we delete the temporary XML Object (i.e. set it to `undefined`) as it's no longer required.

---

**Result**

The example gist above includes the following source XML:

```xml
<films>
  <film name="Foobar" version="2D"></film>
  <film name="Foobar" version="3D"></film>
  <film name="Foobaz" version="2D"></film>
  <film name="Foobaz" version="3D"></film>
  <film name="Foo" version="3D"></film>
  <film name="Quux" version="2D"></film>
  <film name="Quux" version="3D"></film>
</films>
```

which will be transformed to the following:

```xml
<films>
  <film name="Foobar" version="3D"/>
  <film name="Foobar" version="2D"/>
  <film name="Foobaz" version="3D"/>
  <film name="Foobaz" version="2D"/>
  <film name="Foo" version="3D"/>
  <film name="Quux" version="3D"/>
  <film name="Quux" version="2D"/>
</films>
```

---

**Note:** For more complex XML structures and transformation requirements than the example provided in your question, I'd consider utilizing [XSLT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT) instead. Given your current requirement a template like [this one](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQga/) will achieve your desired result.

Comment: Hi first of big thanks for your answer! XSLT seems to be the right tool for the job however is there anyway to apply XSLT rules from within Extendscript?

Comment: If you have a source `.xml` file you can utilize the `document`'s [`importXML()`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Document.html#importXML) method and specify the `.xsl` file (i.e. XSLT template) to use for the transformation by setting the `allowTransform` and `transformFilename` properties of the  [`XMLImportPreference`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_XMLImportPreference.html) class.